# Social Media login (Angular , Spring boot)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm building website angular frontend and backend spring boot, I want to use **angularx-social-login** for authentication but how can secure backend API (Spring boot) to be secure for any user not authentication **angularx-social-login**.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented OAuth with SpringBoot and Angular. Check Spring's guide for implementation at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: it's complicated,  you have another option?